# UIDatePicker change event not firing on first spin Swift

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, ibaction

I am trying to update a label when the UIDatePicker (Count Down Timer) is updated by the user. However, it only updates it after the first spin. The first spin does not change the label value. I have attempted to perform the UI update on the main queue to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well-known and long-standing bug. If you look closely at Apple's projects that use a count down date picker (like the Timer part of the Clock app), they never try to respond to the action of *spinning* the picker; the user has to tap a *button* which then *reads* the value of the picker. I suggest you design your interface similarly.